# FlexSlider startAt with move != 1

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, flexslider

I am using flexslider jQuery plugin I have carousel like this:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $('.flexslider').flexslider({
        animation: "slide",
        animationLoop: false,
        itemWidth: 95,
        itemMargin: 0,
        pausePlay: false,
        move: 3,
        slideshow: false,
        controlNav: false,
        startAt: 1
    });
});
```

My carousel has 6 slides and 3 slides are shown in the viewport. I like the carousel to start from the second slide (startAt: 1), but it is showing slides (4, 5 and 6). How can I make it to show slides (2, 3 and 4) from start and leave move to 3?

If you set up startAt: 2 it will show slides 3, 4 and 5 as it should.